# Understanding Legacy Hardware Filter

Tags: filter

I'm working with a schematic of a legacy signal filtering hardware my company is using and was wondering if anyone can understand/explain what the sections of opamps are doing. I plan on modifying it for a new circuit design but I'm not sure what I'm looking at (my only background with opamps is simplistic things like rectifiers, voltage followers, and amplification).

From a black box perspective, it takes in a noisy waveform, and outputs the waveform's peak value as a nice flat dc value. There are two 20k potentiometers for calibrating the filter. The only output ports are 2x and 4x port depending on what multiplication of the peak value you want.

[image: Black Box Example]

[image: Legacy Signal Filter Schematic]

Comment: Is this the actual schematic or did someone reverse-engineer it?

Comment: I was told it is the signal filtering section of a larger schematic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *was wondering if anyone can understand/explain what the sections of
> op-amps are doing*

When it comes to stuff like this you would benefit highly by simulating the circuit. Anyway, your circuit is: -

- an input amplifier (with a small amount of spectral shaping) followed by
- a precision rectifier followed by
- a unity gain buffer followed by
- two Sallen-Key low-pass filters

> *I plan on modifying it for a new circuit design*

Then you should definitely simulate the circuit and test the new circuit in a simulator. They are free so, the only expense is the learning curve but, that will be paid back tenfold as you develop more circuits in the future.

> *There are two 20k potentiometers for calibrating the filter.*

They are used for adjusting DC offsets.

Comment: Ok thank you so much, I have a better idea now. After simulating it in LTSPICE I'm trying to break it logically into blocks however I'm still struggling on figuring out what some components of the 1st op amp are doing and was wondering if you knew. In particular C4, R1, C6, R10, and R11. I assume R15 and R2 work together to amplify the signal, my calculation are they make a gain of 5.31 (My Math: 1+ 110/25.5 = 5.31)

Comment: @Aaron C4 and R1 slightly raise the gain at higher frequencies. As to why; I have no idea. R10 provides a DC path for op-amp input bias currents. Because I don't know what the input externally connects to I can't say why it needs to do this. C6 is usually not needed in op-amp circuits but, may be deemed by the designer to be needed for some reason. R11 seems to be associated with C6 but, for the same reasons, it's use is obscure.

Comment: If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification. R15 and R2 set the DC gain of the amplifier (1 + 110/25.5).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a blurb on how the rectifier stage works.

https://www.analogictips.com/how-does-a-precision-rectifier-work-faq/